# Browse image is not working for Captured pictures

Tags: android, android-image

I am new in android, in my app, I want to add pictures from Gallery to my Activity. I googled for it, and get some code. But that code is not working for the pics that i captured in my Android device. My device is Xperia S. And i dont know whether thats because of the high resolution or something. I dont know what is it .my code is:

```
Button buttonSelectImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonSelect);
    buttonSelectImage.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, PICK_IMAGE);

        }

    });

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    switch (requestCode) 
    {

        case (PICK_IMAGE):
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
            {

                Uri photoUri = intent.getData();
                if (photoUri != null) 
                {

                        TextView t = (TextView) this
                                .findViewById(R.id.EditTextImage);

                        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                                photoUri, null, null, null, null);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();

                        int idx = cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
                        absoluteFilePathSource = cursor.getString(idx);
                        t.setText(absoluteFilePathSource);

                        BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        opt.inDither = false;
                        opt.inScaled = false;
                        opt.inDensity = 0;
                        opt.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                        opt.inPurgeable = false;
                        opt.inSampleSize = 1;
                        opt.inScreenDensity = 0;
                        opt.inTargetDensity = 0;

                        sourceBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(absoluteFilePathSource,
                                opt);
                }
            }
            break;

    }
}
```

Please anybody help me to find the error. Please..Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it just do nothing or does it crash? Does your logcat say anything relevant? Decoding a large image file without scaling it down will often throw OutOfMemory - as a quick test try 'inSampleSize = 8' and see what the result is.

Comment: It is not doing anything, says. Your app stopped unexpectly.. And i am getting no errors in LogCat or nothing as exception. The image even not loading into my activity

Comment: I didnt get what you mean by inScaleSize.. Can u xplain a little more ?

Comment: If you are seeing 'your app stopped...' then that is a crash and there should be something in logcat. My guess is still OutOfMemory, please see here for an explanation of what I mean: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Ok. lemme see. And can u edit my code and make the changes for what i want with it ? Plz.. That will be a great help. plz